# Drop down box auto select

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, selected

I was wondering how one would go about having this code below to have the option from the user's profile to display the correct state. Right now it defaults to the blank line.

```
<select id="state" name="state" class="input-xlarge form-control">
<option value=""></option>
<?php 
$result = $db->select("SELECT * FROM as_states ORDER BY statename ASC");
foreach($result as $country) 
{
    echo "<option value=\"";
    echo $country['stateid'];
    echo "\">";
    echo $country['statename'];
    echo "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Someone told me on here in the past how to do it this way (below), which is the older PHP version and wanted to know how to make it work in the above statement.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY countrypicks DESC,countryname ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$options="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $countryid=$row["countryid"];
    $countryname=$row["countryname"];
    $selected = ($countryid == $merchcountry) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    $options.="<option value=\"$countryid\" $selected>$countryname</option>";
}
?>
<SELECT NAME="merchcountry">
<option>-------</option>
<? echo $options; ?>
</SELECT>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the headlines where all capital.

Answer (score 0):

the html should look like

```
    <option value="id" selected>name</option>
```

(or selected="selected" if you need to be xhtml compatible )

so something like:

```
    echo "<option value=\"";
    echo $country['stateid'];
    if ( $country['stateid'] == $user_state ) echo " selected";
    echo "\">";
    echo $country['statename'];
    echo "</option>";
```

also:

```
    SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY countrypicks DESC,countryname ASC
```

is overkill if you only need stateid and statename.

Comment: Thank you. I could not figure out why it would not display. Then after looking at the code I saw this: <option value="3 selected">Alabama. So I split this echo "\">"; between the lines. I cannot figure out how to show the code again. It jumbles it all together.